# php mkdir works when called from command line, but not from apache (Windows)

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, apache2.2

I have narrowed down my issue to the following case.

I have a simple file 'test.php'

```
<?php
mkdir("w:/Input/47/");
?>
```

When I run it from command line (php -f test.php), it successfully creates the directory.

When I run it through the windows version of Apache, I get:

```
[17-Dec-2012 16:29:49] PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ReportComp\test.php on line 2
```

I'm running Apache 2.2 (64bit) in Windows 7 (64 bit) as my domain user name (the same one I'm logged into my desktop as)

The 'w' drive is a network drive that (I believe) is also running windows.

Any thoughts?

Comment: As what user does apache run? Maybe apache doesnt have write permission to w: drive? p.s. when you run in console, you probably run as root ?

Comment: Can you log in as the apache user and try to exec the file from command line again? Is drive w:/ available for the apache user? AFAIK Windows newtwork folders can be mounted on a per user or per system policy

Comment: I'm running apache as the same user that I"m logged into my desktop as.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses '\' as directory separator .. possibly this could couse the issue i would sugest you to use '`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`'

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't explain why this works from the command-line and not apache. However, I've tried using both '/' and '\\', both with and without trailing slashes. I have a limitation in that the same path used to create the folder is used by a 3rd party application that doesn't like UNC.